# How do I check whether a package from multiverse is installed?

Tags: apt, repository, multiverse

I am on an Ubuntu system that has the multiverse repository enabled, and I'd like to see whether I can disable it.

How can I check whether any package from multiverse is installed on the system?

Comment: It is not a duplicate. There, they mean a repository URL; `multiverse` is not a repository with a separate URL, but a section within a repository. The answer given there with aptitude doesn't work here; what may work is `aptitude search '?section (multiverse) ?installed'`

Answer (score 5):

Brute force:

```
dpkg --list | grep "^i" | awk '{print $2}' | while read P ; do D=$(apt-cache policy ${P} | grep "multiverse" | head -1) ; if [[ ${#D} -gt 0 ]] ; then echo "${P}:${D}" ; fi ; done
```

Comment: Seems to work, but is super slow.

Comment: @mook765 Yes I've never seen a one-liner sooo sloowww.

Comment: +1 doesn't matter to me that it's slow. It's easy to understand and effective.

Comment: That is basically what I used today. It took over an hour to run, which I wasn't happy with, hence my question. It does work.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is in [synaptic](https://www.lifewire.com/guide-to-synaptic-package-manager-2205707). Or you can use dpkg-query.

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Section}\t\t${Package}\n' | grep -e ^multiverse
```

I revert my incorrect answer.

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^.i/ {print $2}' | xargs apt-cache policy | awk '/^[a-z0-9.\-]+:/ {pkg=$1}; /\*\*\*/ {OFS="\t"; ver=$2; getline; print pkg,ver,$2,$3}'|grep -v /var/lib/dpkg/status| sed -e 's/://'|awk '{printf "%-40s %-36s %-36s %-16s \n",$1,$2,$3, $4}' | grep multiverse
```

Comment: Nope, this command does not work correctly.

Comment: I don't downvote very often but a broken one-liner anyone can quickly test deserves it.

Comment: @mook why not? I'll try the solution from  Wayne Vosberg and get the same two packages.

Comment: @nobody I get totally different results, also checked with synaptics shows that the command you provided doesn't seem to work correctly. Your command results in a single package for me, but this package is from universe. `Section` is not `Origin`.

Comment: `synaptic` displays the origin, but I can't install it on a server. Where does it get its info from?